# Calling Octave interpolation function within function body

Tags: function, octave, interpolation, wrapper

I'm trying to wrap Octave interpolation function in a function body,

```
function FUN = inter(p);
    FUN = interpn (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, A, p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), "spline");
end
```

The reason why I'm doing this is because I'm using a package which function needs a string name function which would be in this case packageFunction("inter", argument1);

The issue is calling now for instance like,

```
  disp("value = "), inter([10 2 4 3 4])
```

doesn't work; Doesn't see the vectors error: 'x1' undefined ,

Of course the vectors xi and matrix A are defined above the function body. Would appreciate advice on this,

thanks, Damir

------------- in file example1.m

```
[a b c] = fminuit('gaussian','mnplot',[10 166 33],[x;y;dy])
```

------------- in file gaussian.m

```
function f = gaussian(par,data);
%theoretical function
f = par(1)/(sqrt(2*pi)*par(3)) * exp(-.5*((data(1,:)- 
par(2))./par(3)).^2); 
if (size(data,1)==2),    %chi-square, error = 1
  f = sum((data(2,:) - f).^2);
 elseif (size(data,1)>2), %chi-square, error = 3rd row of data
 f = sum(((data(2,:) - f)./data(3,:)).^2);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are using an old function that requires a string as the function, the first solution below will not work. This is, however, the right way to do it. Changing the old function to use function handles instead of strings would be my preferred solution. However, you can also use an alternative solution further down below, which uses global variables. This is not the recommended approach ([we should strive to avoid globals](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51946-systematic-do-not-use-global-don-t-use-eval)), but will solve your near-term problems.

### Correct approach: use an anonymous function

You should use an anonymous function, these can capture variables when they're defined:

```matlab
inter = @(p)interpn (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, A, p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), "spline");
```

Now `inter(p)` works just as if `inter` had been declared as a normal function. But the values of `x1`, `x2`, etc as they were defined when `inter` was defined will be stored inside `inter`.

As stated, the function you pass `inter` to must be written to accept function handles.

### Bad, quick solution: use global variables

First, create a file `inter.m` with the following contents:

```matlab
function FUN = inter(p);
    global x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 A
    FUN = interpn (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, A, p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), "spline");
end
```

Next, in your function of script that calls `inter`, again declare the global variables (currently MATLAB warns that you should declare them as globals before giving them a value, in future versions this will be required):

```matlab
global x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 A
x1 = ...
x2 = ...
% etc

inter([10 2 4 3 4])
% or:
fminuit('inter',...)
```

Comment: I did that but doesn't work; The package function has a format as above; The function is defined by string and pulled from a different file. Did you see a structure like this before?

Comment: @damir: That must be some really old function written before function handles existed. A pity. I think the only workaround is to have your function `inter` use global variables.

Comment: Yes, package is from 2011; It seems it follows the concept "https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html"  Minimize a Function Specified by a File; Hmm, would you have an idea how to wrap my "interpn" function into this;  I was looking forward at using this package for fitting.

Comment: LOL. "Fminuit was originally developed for Matlab 4.x". Yes, there were no function handles then. Wow, that's a long time ago!